# HttpClient GetAsync freezes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After authorization, the contact page is loaded. The method is called in the viewmodel page.

```
public partial class Contacts : ContentPage
        {
            ContactsPageViewModels vm;    
            public Contacts()
            {
                vm = new ContactsPageViewModels();
                BindingContext = vm;
                InitializeComponent();
            }
         }
```

I tried to send just 200ok. Everything comes to the http analyzer, but in the application itself it hangs on the first line

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<UserModel>> GetContactsList()
        {
            //freezes in the first line
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:52059/api/Home/GetContacts/" + Convert.ToString(App.User.ID));
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<UserModel>>(responseBody);
        }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetContacts/{id}")]
        public ActionResult GetContacts(int id)
        {
            ObservableCollection<UserModel> users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();

            foreach (UserModel user in db.UserModels)
                users.Add(user); 

            users.Remove(db.UserModels.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id));

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            //return Ok();
            return new JsonResult(users);
        }
```

In postman all work

Comment: it hangs indefinitely or does it continue at some point? what do you mean exactly with hanging?

Comment: What is freezing exactly? The Xanarin app? Where does it freeze? How are you calling `GetContactsList`? Are you doing async all the way up the chain?

Comment: When are you executing the GetContactsList method? In the ViewModel's ctor, or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with synchronization context and being on the main thread of the application.

Read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) or [here](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f).

Try:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<UserModel>> GetContactsList()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:52059/api/Home/GetContacts/" + Convert.ToString(App.User.ID)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<UserModel>>(responseBody);
}
```

What happens is a deadlock, because the main thread is waiting for the async to end. And async want to get back to the thread an end async - but cannot, because the main thread is waiting for it.

`.ConfigureAwait(false)`

will say (not digging into the state machine and how async/await works) that it will end on some other thread, that the calling (main/synchronization) thread.